# Computer Browser service cannot start, "Access Denied"

Tags: windows-7, services

I just noticed that my Windows Event Viewer is flooded with a repeating trio of entries.

> The Computer Browser service entered the running state.
>
> The Computer Browser service entered the stopped state.
>
> The Computer Browser service terminated with the following error:
>   Access is denied.

This occurs every two minutes.

I had a look at the local services.  Computer Browser is set to Manual start under the Local System account.  The Recovery options are set to retry twice after failing with a two minute delay each time.  All of it dependency services are started and it has no dependants.  I can't find any Group Policy's that mention this service by name.

If I try to start it manually, it just gives the usual "Access is denied."

What could be causing this to fail?  How do I get this to work, or should I just disable it?

Comment: Is the question why are you getting the message or why can't you update your policies?

Comment: Sorry, question clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Computer Browser service is the mechanism that collects and
>   distributes the list of workgroups and domains and the servers within
>   them. The list displays in the Microsoft Windows Network window and
>   related windows in My Network Places.

I *believe* it only really applied up to XP and is now legacy. Therefore you may be able to simply disable it.

Or try turning on `Network Discovery` in `Network and Sharing Center`.

Comment: You are correct, Computer Browser service was discontinued after Win2000 and XP.

Comment: Network Discovery is on.  I find it very odd that a computer that has never had Windows XP installed on it would even bother installing this defunct component.  It's good to know I can disable it without reducing functionality.